# Access a constructor into a function on PHP

Tags: php

I want to try to access my constructor $mysql that I have declared ouside the class ( When I put inside the class it wont work ) and I wanted to have access to it inside the methods that I create throught the all class.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$mysql = new DbConnector();
class Validar
{
    private $nifProgram;
    private $checkProgram;
    private $result;

    public function getInfo($nifProgram, $checkProgram)
    {
        $this->nifProgram = $nifProgram;
        $this->checkProgram = $checkProgram;
        echo $this->nifProgram . " - " . $this->checkProgram;
        $this->validate();
        return $this->result;
    }

    private function validate()
    {
    }
}?>
```

If I put inside the class ( like the other variables are ) I get this error: syntax error, unexpected '$mysql', expecting 'function'

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is not in the code you posted.

Comment: pass it to the constructor or individual functions

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in db.php?

Comment: Do you ever call `new Validar()`?

Comment: The error doesn't come from db.php, that class is working on other projects that I have

Comment: Just a tip on your terminology: `$mysql` is not a constructor, a constructor is a function used to create and setup an instance of a class. `$mysql` is just a variable, its value is an instance of the `DbConnector` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass it as a function argument, for instance, to the constructor:

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$mysql = new DbConnector();
$validar = new Validar($mysql);
class Validar
{
    private $nifProgram;
    private $checkProgram;
    private $result;
    private $dbconn;

    public function __construct($dbconn)
    {
        $this->dbconn = $dbconn;
    }

    public function frobnicate()
    {
        //Now you can access the db connector as:
        $this->dbconn;
    }

    public function getInfo($nifProgram, $checkProgram)
    {
        $this->nifProgram = $nifProgram;
        $this->checkProgram = $checkProgram;
        echo $this->nifProgram . " - " . $this->checkProgram;
        $this->validate();
        return $this->result;
    }

    private function validate()
    {
    }
}?>
```

As far as the error you get when you try to put it inside the class, e.g.:

```
class Validar 
{
    $mysql = new DbConnector();
}
```

What this looks like to the php parser is that you're declaring an member variable (a "property") of the class, named `mysql`, and you're trying to initialize it using the statement `new DbConnector()`. Unfortunately, PHP only allows you to initialize properties using constant expressions, such as string or numeric literals, `null`, etc. From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value

So you could also just instantiate the `DbConnector` directly in the constructor function, if you don't need to be able to pass it in. Either way would work fine, it all just depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The error is appearing somewhere inside of the brackets of a

```
class XXXXXX 
{
    //error is on this level
    //maybe you put here:
    $mysql = new Validar(); // or some other logic stuff
    //where it expects either variable declaration only
    //or a method
}
```

Comment: If I put it like that, it will give me the error that I have post it on my question: unexpected '$mysql', expecting 'function'

Comment: That's what I'm saying.